# Return a variable on uploadstring completed

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to send a POST request using WebClient and I am using "UploadStringAsync" in order to stop the UI from freezing. I want to return a variable after the upload is completed, but I am getting an error:

```
try
{
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    //Contact the API
    using (WebClient getResults = new WebClient())
    {

    ...

        //Send the POST and get the result!

        getResults.UploadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            dynamic finalResult = JObject.Parse(e.Result);//finalResults.selectedProfile.name 
            results.Add(finalResult.selectedProfile.name);
            return (results.toArray()); //Error is here
        };

        getResults.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(URL), "POST", postInfo);
    }

    //This is what was there before: return (results.ToArray());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
```

The error I receive is:

> Since 'System.Net.UploadStringCompletedEventHandler' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: Why don't you just write a function that takes as parameter your array and call it at the end of your handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use some async constructions, I hope that firstly you have to write asyn function like below.

```
static async Task<string> GetData()
    {
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            return await webClient.UploadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/"), "POST", string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Then you can wait for result and parse.

```
    Task<string> getDataTask = GetData();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(getDataTask.Result))
    {
        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        dynamic finalResult = JObject.Parse(getDataTask.Result);
        results.Add(finalResult.selectedProfile.name);
    }
```

However, what I think is that when we deal with UI freezing, for example in WPF applications, we should use **multithreading**, but no asyc.